# Dynamically Show Home Button in Header Bar in Ionic

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

In my Ionic app I want to show a Back To Home button in the header bar on all pages except the Home page. I try to do this with a boolean that is set to false when the $state.current.name equals home.

In an ng-show directive I use this boolean to show or hide the home button. Unfortunately, the boolean is always set to true and therefore the button is also shown on the home page. How can I solve this?

My controller in app.js

```
.controller('mainController', function($scope, $state) {
    $scope.showHomeButton = true;

    if ($state.current.name == 'home') {
        $scope.showHomeButton = false;
    }
})
```

Extract from the index.html

```
<body ng-app="chartly" ng-controller="mainController">
  <ion-nav-bar class="bar-positive">
      <ion-nav-back-button class="button-clear">
          <i class="icon ion-ios-arrow-left"></i>
      </ion-nav-back-button>
      <ion-nav-buttons side="right" ng-show="showHomeButton">
          <a href="/#/home" class="button icon ion-home"></a>
      </ion-nav-buttons>
  </ion-nav-bar>
  <ion-nav-view>
  </ion-nav-view>
```

Answer (score 0):

Either add a watch :

```
$scope.$watch(function(){
    return $state.current.name;
}, function(new){
    if (new === 'home') {
        $scope.showHomeButton = false;
    }
});
```

Or if this doesn't work listen for then event $stateChangeSuccess in your main controller

```
$rootScope.$on('$stateChangeSuccess',function(event, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams){ 
if (toState.name === 'home') {
        $scope.showHomeButton = false;
    }

}
```

Comment: The solution with $rootScope always results in false. In fact, toState.name is always equal to 'home'. Do you have any idea why this does not change?

Comment: use ui-sref directive in template to trigger state navigation instead of href (you may need to add href="#" on <a> tag but ui-sref works on button or div tags too). Or use $state.go in javascript. Documentation : http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-router/site/#/api/ui.router.state.directive:ui-sref

Answer (score 0):

Did you try using $location instead?

```
.controller('mainController', function($scope, $location) {
    if($location.path()!='#/home') {
        $scope.showHomeButton = true;
    }
})
```

Comment: $location.path() gives / as a result on all pages. Do you have any idea why?